# Save FITS table: The keyword description with its value is too long

Tags: python, astropy

I get an error when trying to save astropy Tables retrieved using astroquery to FITS files. In some case it complains that the description of some keywords is too long. The `writeto()` function seems to have a `output_verify` argument to avoid this kind of problem, but I cannot find how to pass it to the `write()` function? Does it exist? 
Here is my code:

```
import astropy.units as u
from astroquery.vizier import Vizier
import astropy.coordinates as coord
from astropy.table import Table

akari_query=Vizier(columns=["S09","S18","e_S09","e_S18","q_S09","q_S18"],catalog=["II/297/irc"])
result=akari_query.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=200.0, dec=10.0,unit=(u.deg, u.deg),frame='icrs'), width=[2.0*u.deg,2.0*u.deg],return_type='votable')
table=Table(result[0], masked=True)
table.write('test.fits')
```

It returns a long error message ending with:

```
ValueError: The keyword description with its value is too long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `table.meta['description']` is longer than allowed for the header of the fits file you're trying to save. You can simply shorten it to anything below 80 characters and try to write `test.fits` again:

```
table.meta['description'] = u'AKARI/IRC All-Sky Survey Point Source Catalogue v. 1.0'
table.write('test.fits')
```

Comment: That does it, thanks! I was looking at the columns descriptions, not the table description...

Comment: Maybe the I/O connector for FITS tables should actually catch this exception and handle it better, since it's not obvious (especially if you're not familiar with the FITS format) where it would be coming from...